# Calculate difference of two numbers on the 360 circle with the sign/direction

Tags: arithmetic, circles, angle

There are a couple of answers to this question, but they leave out the sign.  Is there a clever way to determine if the angle is positive or negative?

This nice formula gives the angle, but not the direction - any clever hints?
$$
d(,) = \min\{360−|A-B|,|A-B|\}
$$

Comment: I don't understand what does "two numbers on the circle" mean. Do you mean there are two points, $A$ and $B$, lying on the unit circle? If so, in what sense are you trying to find the difference between them? Are you trying to find the difference in their respective angles? Please update your question, an example would be a great help.

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup of my question!  :) I have a lot of angles - 234, 250 or 353, 15 or 50,60  and I want to know the difference between these numbers, and the sign of the difference.  The formula in my question gives the angle perfectly - what I'd like to also capture is a simple way to get the sign (clockwise or counter-clockwise).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are given a pair of angles $A$ and $B$ on the standard $360^\circ$ circle and would like to know the direction of the difference angle between them.

Firstly, the actual difference formula you cite assumes $A,B$ are between $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$, it won't work with larger angles. For example, $720^\circ = 0^\circ$ since it's just 2 rotations around the full circle, and so is $1440^\circ$, but your formula will not give $0^\circ$, just be careful with it.

The direction of the difference is given by the sign of the actual difference $A-B$. In other words, the difference is positive when
$$
A > B \iff A - B > 0 \iff \mathrm{sign}(A-B) = 1.
$$

Comment: If I have two angles - 350° and 10° - the difference between them is 20° and it can be computed with the previous formula.  In this case, we can say that the sign is 1 or -1, doesn't matter.  How would I compute the sign if the numbers are 10° and 350°?  Same absolute value of 20°, but how can I compute the sign?

Answer (score 0):

[sign map of d(A,B)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRKpZ.png)
You have to make a choice which sign to chose. Turning A towards B or turning B towards A. This is my choice. The sing flips when you cross the 180 degree difference angle I would say. Try to turn this into a function.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the image - that's pretty clear.  I was hoping that there was a mathematical "trick" to avoid having to write case statements or if/then/else statements, but if that's the only way...

Answer (score 0):

I found a formula that works - seems trivial now that I have it.

```
=MIN(360-ABS(A-B),ABS(A-B))*(IF(ABS(A-B)>180,-1,1)*SIGN(A-B))
```

This is the excel formula I use and it works fine.  A and B are the inputs and of course in Excel it would be A1 or A2 or ... and the same for B1 B2, etc.

The MIN function gets me the number of degrees difference between the two angles on the circle.  To get the sign, I subtract A and B, and if the difference between the two angles is greater than 180, I invert the sign.  Thanks to those of you that helped me find this solution!